# Find the cardinality of this element

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

1. Consider p(x)=x^2 - 4x - 12

The set $A$ = $\{x/2,\mid p(x)=0\}, B = \{x/y \mid x ∈ A, y ∈ A\}, C = \{k · x |k, x ∈ N∗ $ and $ p(x) < 0\}. $

Questions :

A) Find the cardinality of the set B, and determine if B is a subset of $Z$ (integers).

Answer :
Since p(x) is a quadratic equation, I found that X = -2 and X = 6 when p(x) = 0. 
So the set A would therefore be the set of the following elements -1 and 3 (because I did -2/2, and 6/2)

Since B is x/y, I did $3/-1, -1/3, -1/-1, 3/3$. Which gives me $-3, -1/3, 1$.
So B has a cardinality of 3.

Also since we have -1/3, then B cannot be a subset of Z.

Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $A= \{-1,3\}$, I agree.

So it follows that $B=\{-\frac{1}{3}, -3, 1\}$ so indeed size $3$. It's not a subset of $\Bbb Z$ because of the $-\frac{1}{3}$ element.

So I quite agree with you.

(as an aside: check this answer's formatting to improve your own)